# Javascript async/await function in async/await function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const function1 = () => {
   let isSuccess = false

   function2(
       // This a synchronous function it always return true or false. If result is true, ı want to change value of isSuccess as true
   )
 return isSuccess
}
```

funtions2 is a synchronous function it always return true or false. If result is true, ı want to change value of isSuccess as true. But isSuccess always return false. Because function2 takes a little time. and ı want to wait return isSuccess until come result of function2. I search on stackoverflow there are some examples but ı dont understand Please help me

Comment: This doesn't need to be async.

Comment: how can ı do this @evolutionxbox

Comment: You can return the result of `function2`. `function1 = () => function2()`? --- If this doesn't work, please update your question. Make sure the example is a runnable [mcve]

Comment: You mentioned async/await twice. What, if anything, is asynchronous here?

Comment: You've said *"funtions2 is a synchronous function"* and *"But isSuccess always return false. Because function2 takes a little time."* If `function2` is synchronous, you won't be able to see what value `isSuccess` has because nothing can access it while `function2` is running (other than code in `function2`). I'm afraid it's not at all clear what you're really dealing with here. Please have a read through [this](/help/mcve) and follow the suggestions there.

Comment: `isSuccess` is always false because you don't update its value with the return value of `function2`.

Comment: If function2 is an async function (defined with async) then it returns a promise. With that in mind you should be able to do this:

`const function1 = async () => {
  const isSuccess = await function2();
  return isSuccess;
}`

Comment: do you actually *call* function2 somewhere? for instance `isSuccess = function2()` somewhere in the body of function1 ... You can also update the value of `isSuccess` inside the body of function2, if you want to. But again, you'll have to call function2 somewhere ...

Comment: @MustafaUysal please check if this helps you https://jsfiddle.net/rj0179wp/

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'm assuming `function2` is asynchronous and performs some kind of async work. I'm simulating that async work in the code below with the `delay` function.

In your code, you do not *call* `function2`; the `()` is missing from the function call.

Also, the call is not `await`ed. Since `function2` is async, it will begin running but execution will continue on as `await` is required to tell JS you want to wait until the function's returned promise is resolved before continuing.

If this is still unclear, I advise you read the MDN docs on [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

The following is a working example:

```js
const function2 = async () => {
  try {
    // .. do some async stuff, such as:
    const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
    await delay(3000)
    
    return true;
  }
  catch {
    return false;
  }
}

const function1 = async () => {
  let isSuccess = false;
  isSuccess = await function2();
  
  return isSuccess;
}


// Test it out:
async function main(){
  console.log("calling function1...");
  console.log("function1 returned: " + await function1());
};
main();
```